# How to get a list of Wikipedia pages that contain certain types of content tables?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

What is the best way to get a list of all Wikipedia pages that contain certain types of content tables such as 'Nutritional value' table and 'Scientific classification' table?

Positive examples:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macadamia

Negative examples:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower_seed (only Nutritional value table)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar (only Nutritional value table)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helianthus (only Scientific classification table)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably try a combination of [search API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsearch) and [`hastemplate:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Searching#hastemplate:) search feature:

- Pages that have both [`Template:Taxobox`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Taxobox) and [`Template:Infobox nutritional value`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_nutritional_value):
  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=hastemplate:Taxobox%20hastemplate:%22Infobox%20nutritional%20value%22
  (currently 76 hits, including Lemon)
- Pages that have both [`Template:Automatic taxobox`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Automatic_taxobox) and [`Template:Infobox nutritional value`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_nutritional_value): https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=hastemplate:%22Automatic%20taxobox%22%20hastemplate:%22Infobox%20nutritional%20value%22&srlimit=500
  (currently 17 hits, including Macadamia)